# Identical Meaning of "similar to" and "like"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Whenever I use the phrase "similar to", Microsoft Word wants me to use "like" instead. I'm not a native speaker, so maybe I'm getting the nuances wrong here. But to me, "A is similar to B" would indicate that both objects are still quite distinct, whereas in "A is like B" they are pracitcally the same.

How do you feel about this (especially native speakers)?

Comment: Maybe "identical"?

Comment: Both are used to cover a range of degrees of correspondence. Usually, a restriction is added (A is similar to B in that they both melt on hot days). // Otherwise, individual examples may be informed by style preferences. "He _is_ like his mother." "The model J was similar to the model B." 'Similar to' is somewhat more formal.

Comment: As a native speaker, I turn off Microsoft Word grammar checker. It is very bad.

Comment: Two different Questions, japhwil.

Broadly, "similar to" and "like" are interchangeable (and MS should leave your style choices to you).

Quite separately, I think you'll have a hard time explaining the difference you suggest between " A is similar to B" indicating objects are quite distinct, and "A is like B" suggesting they are practically the same.

Don't you think you'd get more suitable help at SE English Language Learners?